# Deleting rows in a data frame which has common column value in another data frame in python

Tags: python, dataframe

This is data frame 1:

```
       Date     name    Age 
0   2015-01-02  Adam    1   
1   2015-02-02  David   2   
2   2015-02-02  Mila    2   
3   2015-03-02  Harshan 2   
4   2015-03-02  Hardik  2   
5   2015-03-02  Alex    3
```

This is data frame 2:

```
    Date        name        Age 
0   2015-01-02  Jadeja      1   
1   2015-02-02  Dravid      2   
2   2015-02-02  Dhoni       2   
3   2015-03-02  Hrithik     2   
4   2015-03-02  Hardik      2   
5   2015-03-02  Alex        3
```

Now I want to delete rows in data frame 1 where there are common values in name column of both data frames

This is the expected output:

```
           Date     name    Age 
0   2015-01-02  Adam        1   
1   2015-02-02  David       2   
2   2015-02-02  Mila        2   
3   2015-03-02  Harshan     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` using `indicator=True` to indicate where the values come from and keep only those from the first dataframe ("left_only"):

```
(df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
    .query('_merge == "left_only"')
    .drop('_merge', axis=1)
)
```

*NB. if you need to limit the columns used for the match, use the `on` option in `merge`: for example `on=['Date', 'name']`*

output:

```
         Date     name  Age
0  2015-01-02     Adam    1
1  2015-02-02    David    2
2  2015-02-02     Mila    2
3  2015-03-02  Harshan    2
```

intermediate data after the first step of the pipeline:

```
         Date     name  Age      _merge
0  2015-01-02     Adam    1   left_only
1  2015-02-02    David    2   left_only
2  2015-02-02     Mila    2   left_only
3  2015-03-02  Harshan    2   left_only
4  2015-03-02   Hardik    2        both
5  2015-03-02     Alex    3        both
6  2015-01-02   Jadeja    1  right_only
7  2015-02-02   Dravid    2  right_only
8  2015-02-02    Dhoni    2  right_only
9  2015-03-02  Hrithik    2  right_only
```